# How to host an AngularJS app in Heroku using Node.js WITHOUT using yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, express, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to push a Hello World build with AngularJS into Heroku using Node.js. BUT with multiple views(partials).

I first deployed a Hello World without using ngRoute, meaning: without partials. That was fine and smooth. Then, I tried to push 2 simple partials. But I believe the issue is hosting the application and at the same time asking for partials. I know it is not the right approach and I want your advice.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<head>
    <meta name="name" content="something">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <section ng-view=""></section>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('main', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$http', function ($routeProvider, $http){
        console.log('hola');
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            resolve: **??? I tried with templateUrl but did not work either**
            ,controller: 'indexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/second', {
            resolve: **???**
            ,controller: 'secondCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }])
    .controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = "Hello World";
    }])
    .controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = "World Hello";
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial 'templates/second.html'

```
<h1>{{ helloWorld }}<h1>
<a href="#/" title="">Go to First</a>
```

Partial 'templates/index.html'

```
<h1>{{ helloWorld }}<h1>
<a href="#/second" title="">Go to Second</a>
```

My express app:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});
app.get('/index', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile('templates/index.html', {root: __dirname })
});
app.get('/second', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile('templates/second.html', {root: __dirname })
});
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

And obviously, Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

All the tutorials that I've found so far use Yeoman but I don't want to use Yeoman or any other scaffolding (if that is what that is) tool.

Q: Is it possible to host an AngularJS app in the same Heroku application where I'm storing the partials? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found my issue looking at [this](http://runnable.com/VCOwg1sFidxMyYxV/angularjs-basic-example-for-express-node-js-and-angular-js) example.

The actual issue was that I was not making "public" the directory with express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

### **Here is the hello world**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<head>
    <meta name="name" content="something">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <section ng-view=""></section>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('main', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
        console.log('hola');
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/index.html'
            ,controller: 'indexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/second.html'
            ,controller: 'secondCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }])
    .controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = "Hello World";
    }])
    .controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = "World Hello";
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server / index.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node index.js
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<h1>{{ helloWorld }}<h1>
<a href="#/second" title="">Go to Second</a>
```

**templates/second.html**

```
<h1>{{ helloWorld }}<h1>
<a href="#/" title="">Go to First</a>
```

I hope this helps someone.

To answer my question. Yes, it is possible, what I was doing wrong is not making the templates(files) accessible. If you want to have extra security on what can be accessible you could create a folder called, for example, public. Then make that directory static:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

then you can also have different routes to communicate with your application even RESTfully. Like:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json({...});
});
```

Comment: good one, thanks. Do we need package.json to deploy in heroku?

Comment: Yes, package.json tells Heroku about your app's dependencies: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

Comment: hello. i'm trying to host node.js+ angular.js on heroku but i fail. can i have a zip with your working example please ?

Comment: Hi @AlainIb, unfortunately, it has been so long that I no longer have the app on Heroku. Maybe you could post a question and post the logs so that someone can help. I do remember copying and pasting all the files in this solution, so I don't think you would have found anything in there. Another tip, one time I messed something with the app in Heroku and I had to fully delete it and create it again and that fixed some issues (but I'm just guessing here). Sorry I couldn't be of more help, good luck!