# Angular deployment to Heroku - how to specify app

Tags: angularjs, heroku, deployment, build

I have written a small application in AngularJS, which works fine on my local environment, now I'm deploying to Heroku. But Heroku can't find my app. I must be missing a vital part needed to specify the build and deployment details. So what is needed to run an angular app on Heroku?

Here's what i've done so far:

- Used NPM to create a package.json file in the root of my project
- created a Procfile in the root of my package, specifying my app :

  ```
  web node app.js
  ```
- added an angular buildpack to Heroku (https://github.com/nknj/heroku-buildpack-yo-angular.git works great)

when I use the Heroku CLI, for example `heroku restart` to refresh my dyno (and bear in mind i am running this from WITHIN the project root folder, so I shouldn't have to specify app name) I get the following error:

```
 ▸    Error: No app specified
 ▸    Usage: heroku restart [DYNO] --app APP
 ▸    We don't know which app to run this on.
 ▸    Run this command from inside an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP
 ▸    
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands
```

Heroku can't find my app. Why? How does one tell Heroku how to bootstrap the app? 
Thanks.

Comment: Funny and frustrating, I am having kind of the same issue here, just posted a little ago:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256181/deploying-an-anguilarjs-app-on-heroku-using-ci-cd/43256497
Let me know if you find an answer pls.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy with CLI? From your error it sounds like you are not specifying Your Heroku App,
If you have several heroku apps, you must type  heroku restart --a app_name

Comment: Yes, @moplin, it looks like exactly the same problem!